# How to add DNS Records for Resend on Railway.app?

Tags: deployment, dns, railway, resend.com

So I need to add DNS Records for custom email domain from Resend on my app that is deployed on Railway.app with the free plan, it's just a small freelance project that I kind of play around with and learn new things, but I can't seem to find a possibility to add DNS record on Railway.

I tried to google it or use AI but still can't seem to find solution. I'm thinking of deploying it on vercel instead. Any ideas?